Почему не работает статика в Django?
При рендеринге страницы почему-то не работает статика (css, js) в django. Я запускаю проект через docker контейнеры. Однако, даже не отображается html код на странице, не говоря уже про стили. Вроде бы монтирую все файлы правильно, но всё равно белый экран, не понимаю в чём проблема.
Работаю по такой логике:

Собираю статику python3 manage.py collectstatic локально.
Статика сохраняет в папку staticfiles в корневую папку проекта (внутри стили для admin и для сайта непосредственно).
Далее в docker-compose.yml монтирую ВСЕ файлы в контейнер c django, а в контейнере с nginx монтирую статику из контейнера с django внутрь контейнера nginx в определенную папку.
Прописыаю путь в default.conf в nginx.
Запускаю docker compose up -d, захожу внутрь каждого контейнера docker exec -it <id> bash и вроде бы всё в порядке, то есть в контейнере с django статика есть, а также в контейнере nginx статика тоже есть (пути с кодом ниже), однако всё равно пустая страница (белый фон). Nginx самостоятельно умеет отдавать статику, однако что-то неверно я сделал на каком-то этапе ранее.

Dockerfile
# Создаем кастомный image для Django.
# Кастомный, так как нам надо перекинуть локальные файлы в образ.
# Для PostgreSQL мы возьмем готовый образ и соберем его сразу в docker-compose.yml.
# Docker-compose.yml файл, при помощи которого мы объединяем images и создаем полный сервис для Docker.

# копируем готовый образ python из dockerhub
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

# установка необходимых пакетов для работы с MongoDB
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev libffi-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache bash \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache libpq

# устанавливаем рабочую директорию внутри docker контейнера
WORKDIR /website

# копируем файлы зависимостей и проекта Django в образ
COPY requirements.txt .

# устанавливаем зависимости для проекта, не кешируя их
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# устанавливаем порт, на котором будет работать Docker
EXPOSE 8000

# в рабочую директорию копируем папку с Django вне контейнера
COPY website .

# cобираем статику для Django
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# запускаем через uwsgi
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--ini", "/website/uwsgi.ini" ]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8' 
  
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./website:/website"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  
  mongo:
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db/
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGODB_NAME=production_database
      - MONGODB_USER=manager
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=123qwe
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_django
    volumes:
      - "./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
      - "./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./website/staticfiles:/etc/nginx/website/staticfiles"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - django

volumes:
  mongodb_data:

nginx.conf
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

default.conf
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-CSRFToken $cookie_csrftoken;
    }
    
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000/admin/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /etc/nginx/website/staticfiles/;
    }
}

Пути

К статике локально: /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/ArtemSheptalin/website/staticfiles
Внутри контейнера джанго: /website/staticfiles
Внутри контейнера nginx: /etc/nginx/website/staticfiles

И ввроде бы всё правильно и логично, то не работает. Стоит отметить, как только я удаляю строку <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.min.css' %}" /> в base.html, то появляется хотя бы html на странице...

Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — какую конкретно ссылку генерирует вот этот {% static 'css/main.min.css' %} и что происходит если попробовать перейти по ней?

@andreymal Если я перехожу по ссылке http://localhost:8080/static/css/main.min.css, то на странице отображается содержимое файла main.min.css.

А вообще-то не должно, в показанных вами файлах нет никаких причин, почему localhost:8000 вообще должен был бы работать. Значит вы или забыли почистить кэш браузера, или вы что-то не договариваете

Кроме того, вы не уточнили, является ли это той самой ссылкой, которую сгенерировал {% static 'css/main.min.css' %}, если это она и есть — значит вы неверно настроили STATIC_URL, потому что никакого localhost:8000 там быть в принципе не должно

@andreymal Так localhost:8000  у меня и не работает, приложение запускается на порту 8080, а по поводу ссылки - да, это да, что указана в настройках STATIC_URL = "static/" STATICFILES_DIRS = [    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), ] STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
